# Where did the leg go?

Tags: plot-explanation, jurassic-park

In **Jurassic Park**, the two kids are in the car at night and there is the T-Rex trying to get them...all the while their torch is flashing.
When the leg landed on the car sunroof glass as seen here:

The leg is there and lands on the roof, but then in this attack on the same night in the same place just minutes after the leg landed on the car:

When the dinosaur attacks, the leg isn't there anymore. Did the dinosaur eat it, or did someone quickly throw it away? What happened to it?

Answer (score 9):

Seems to me that it's just a continuity error. The leg disappears temporarily even in the first video clip in the question: [At 0:51](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=51&v=1koa2xAxCAw) the leg falls on the sunroof, [at 1:21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=81&v=1koa2xAxCAw) it's gone, and [at 1:53](https://youtu.be/1koa2xAxCAw?t=1m53s) it's back.